# Catalogue Price Rules

Tags: catalog, catalog-price-rules

I need to create a rule on our site where two different products are linked in the same discount.

The rule I need is: Buy product x for £35 or product x and y for £55.

Not sure what the best way to do this is.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy. Suppose:
1.If product X is £35.
2.If product Y is £30.(or whatever you want)
3.And you want to give £10 discount if customer buys X and Y together. See the screenshot:

Conditions tab:
[image]

Actions tab:
[image]